# Multiple <slug:slug> urlpatterns on the root

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Manual type in of URLs are super important for the website I'm working on. Almost all traffic will come from people going directly to `domain.com/some-string/`. Minimal traffic will come from search engines.

This means making URLs as easy to remember as for people is very important.

Is there a way to have multiple `path('<slug:slug>/', ...)` URL patterns in the root directory?

For example my models:

```
from django.db import models    
class Category(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'categories'
  title  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
  description = models.TextField()
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Widget(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
  # and various other parameters specific to Widget
  category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name = 'widgets', null=True)  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

And my views:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Category, Widget
  
class WidgetDetailView(DetailView):
  model = Widget
  slug_field = 'slug'
  slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'

class CategoryListView(ListView):
  model = Category
  slug_field = 'slug'
  slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
```

And my URLs:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import WidgetDetailView, CategoryListView

urlpatterns = [
  path('<slug:slug>/', WidgetDetailView.as_view(), name='widget-detail')
  path('<slug:slug>/', CategoryListView.as_view(), name='category-list')
]
```

But obviously this works for `domain.com/widget-slug/` but not `domain.com/category-slug/` because only the first URL pattern gets called and results in a 404.

I thought one solution would be to create a GenericRelation in both the Widget and the Category model to a Slug model. A slug 'view' could then return the correct model view by using 'content_type.model' and 'content_object.pk'. But this seems like an unnecessarily complicated solution to what I thought would be a common problem.

Am I missing something obvious? I can't seem to find anyone else trying to achieve this when I search for things like 'multiple slug patterns on root'.

I know it's not an ideal way to structure URLs but like I said type in traffic is critical for this website. Making the URLs as easy to remember as possible is very important.

Thanks.

Comment: What if a `Category` and a `Widget` have the same slug?

Comment: Yes that's another problem I will need to prevent if I have to use my GenericRelation solution. Due to the nature of the site they wouldn't have the same slug. But obviously I need to make sure admins don't accidentally create conflicting slugs.

Comment: I've never heard of a website where the majority of traffic comes from users manually typing the path, mind giving a little insight into what you're doing? Slightly off-topic sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 : Dispatch view**

You can create a `dispatch_view` like this :

*urls.py*

```py
urlpatterns = [
  path('<slug:slug>/', dispatch_view, name='dispatch')
]
```

*views.py*

```py
from django.http import Http404

def dispath_view(request, slug):
    try:
        Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        try:
            Widget.objects.get(slug=slug)
        except Widget.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Not found")
        else:
            return WidgetDetailView.as_view()(request, slug)
    else:
        return CategoryListView.as_view()(request, slug)
```

**Solution 2 : Dispatch Model**

To go deeper, you can create a `Dispatch` Model that would store every slug for your models (on `save()` and on `delete()` ) like the following (untested) to prevent slug duplicates between `Widget` and `Category`:

```py
class Dispatch(models.Model):

    class ViewChoices(models.TextChoices):
        CATEGORY = 'CAT', 'myapp.views.CategoryListView'
        WIDGET = 'WDT', 'myapp.views.WidgetDetailView'

    view = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=ViewChoices.choices,
        default=ViewChoices.CATEGORY,
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

And the associated view :

```py
from django.utils.module_loading import import_string

def dispath_view(request, slug):
    try:
        dispatch_obj = Dispatch.objects.get(slug=slug)
    except Dispatch.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404()
    else:
        view = import_string(dispatch_obj.get_view_display()).as_view()
        return view(request, slug)
```

**Solution 3 : With Model Inheritance**

Another approach is to use model inheritance to prevent slug duplicates between `Widget` and `Category`: :

```
class BaseSlug(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Widget(BaseSlug):
    ...

class Category(BaseSlug):
    ...
```

And use view from solution 1

Comment: Thanks this looks like a potential elegant solution. I will try tomorrow and report back (getting late UK time). Thanks.

Comment: lol, without the spoon feeding this exactly what @ruohola said. Dunno why that was downvoted.

Comment: Yes exactly, I was wondering, ruohola answer is correct.

Comment: It was not me that downvoted @ruohola. My account is still too new to cast votes. I had seen his answer hence my comment. Which I think you have now solved for me by pointing me to `import_string`. Thank you both for helping I appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I think this is a lot simpler with [table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). Use a slug only non-abstract model and let category and widget inherit from it. You can then use a unique slug field. Probably better if your model has "name" and "slug" and then use [Django Autoslug](https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug) with `populate_from="name"` and `unique=True`. Everything would just flow naturally and no hidden coupling between a model and view through import string.

Comment: @Melvyn Table inheritance would be good solution too, but how this would prevent from coupling models and views through import_string ? Since each views can have their own logic ?

Comment: @Melvyn I have added your suggestion in the post.

Comment: Thank you both. Yep @Melvyn inheritance makes a lot of sense. It didn't feel very DRY when I had the title and slug fields repeated. It also takes care of keeping slugs unique too. I also added a CharField to specify the view in the inherited table. Just need to make it a bit more admin friendly now. @Charlesthk I think the last few lines of your despatch view in solution 2 you meant `        view = import_string(dispatch_obj.get_view_display()).as_view()
        return view`

Comment: I would override `get_object()` and return `BaseModel.category` since OneToOne reverse creates an attribute that is the lowercase of the model name. Then return 2 different templates in `get_template_name()`. Unless the views really need their own logic, but most of the time, you can get away with different templates and perhaps some logic in get_context_data() for additional variables. So you really have one view, serving two different models, using two different templates. If you can't get away with that, then the above answer has the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to make a single view which then handles dispatching to the correct model type based on the passed slug. You cannot map the same path pattern to more than one view in any way.

Comment: Any ideas how I could use `content_type.model` and `content_object.pk` in the 'slug' view to dynamically call the correct view? Would like to avoid a bunch of conditionals on  'content_type.model'. Is there a way to return a view that you have identified with a string? Something _like_ `return (slug.content_type.model + 'DetailView(' + str(content_object.pk) +')')`